# Is the sql query correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to question the Product criteria in the table.
The NAME and VAL values are in the different rows.
I question whether the records are equal to NAME = aa, bb, cc,. and VAL = 10,20,30.
I'm turning results. I think the SQL query is working properly.
I was able to correct query the columns with the following method.

But I think it's wrong for performance. Is this SQL query proper from performance aspect? If not, can you give an example for the correct SQL query? Thank you for your help.

```
test table:

Id  PID NAME VAL
1   1   aa   10
2   1   bb   20
3   1   cc   30

4   2   aa   10
5   2   bb   20
6   2   cc   30

7   3   aa   10
8   3   bb   20
9   3   cc   999



Query:

SELECT PID from test WHERE
PID IN (SELECT PID FROM test WHERE NAME='aa' and VAL='10')
AND
PID IN (SELECT PID FROM test WHERE NAME='bb' and VAL='20')
AND
PID IN (SELECT PID FROM test WHERE NAME='cc' and VAL='30')
GROUP BY (PID)



Result:

1
2
```

I'm thinking of using it with such (<> =) operators. This was the final result. I want you to comment if it's true.

```
SELECT t.pid from test t 
WHERE
(t.name = 'aa' and t.val = 10)
OR 
(t.name = 'bb' and t.val = 20) 
OR 
(t.name = 'cc' and t.val > 30) 
GROUP BY t.pid 
HAVING count(t.pid) = 3;
```

Comment: I compiled all the possible approaches for intersect here. Including Yidna's answer: http://www.anicehumble.com/2019/04/sql-intersect.html

Comment: Here's the execution plan. It's not so conclusive, the data is too few. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1f1df698477ead6dea05ff035baa7f6d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend aggregation for this purpose.  Assuming you don't have name/val duplicates, then:

```
select t.pid
from test t
where (t.name, t.val) in ( ('aa', '10'), ('bb', '20'), ('cc', '30') )
group by t.pid
having count(*) = 3;
```

If you can have duplicates, then use:

```
having count(distinct t.name, t.val)
```

Comment: That's a much nicer query. Thanks, Gordon.

Comment: Oooh cool, I didn't know you could use sets. Might I recommend `COUNT(*) > 2` rather than `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for handling duplicates?

Comment: If I need the < >= operators in this query, how can I do?

Comment: I did something like that.    |  
select t.pid 
from test t 
where 
(t.name = 'aa' and t.val = 10) 
OR
(t.name = 'bb' and t.val = 20) 
OR
(t.name = 'cc' and t.val > 30) 
group by t.pid 
having count(t.pid) = 3;

Answer (score 1):

You can also write

```
SELECT a.PID
FROM   test a, test b, test c
WHERE  (a.NAME = 'aa' AND a.VAL = '10') AND
       (b.NAME = 'bb' AND b.VAL = '20') AND
       (c.NAME = 'cc' AND c.VAL = '30') AND
       (a.PID = b.PID AND b.PID = c.PID);
```

I'm not too sure about the performance as the query optimizer might reduce both of these into the same query, but it should not perform worse than your current one.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest.
The query is returning the result I want.
Also this SQL query looks better.
in the other there was too much (SELECT).

Answer (score 0):

What your query doing is basically similar to this:

```
SELECT PID 
FROM test 
WHERE NAME IN ('aa','bb','cc') 
AND VAL IN ('10','20','30')
GROUP BY PID;
```

Unless, you have other condition you would like to add.

Comment: I’d say he doesn’t want the query to return a positive result if  NAME = aa and VAL = 30  for example

Comment: Ooo ok ok, I get what you mean @Kaiser. I look at the results only

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
But this does not give the result I want.

Comment: Ok @mceran . Sorry, I misunderstand your question ;)